# Python: Use format() for dictionary branches

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've this dictionary:

```
info={
    "name": "Naser",
    "key1": "Good morning {name}",
    "key2": "Good evening {name}",
    "key3": "Good night {name}",
    "list1":["word1","word2",{"user": "{name}"}],
}
```

I want to format it with its branches using for loop. Same this:

```
for item in info:
    info[item].format(**info)
```

But I'm getting error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'`

When remove the `list1`  from `info` dictionary the program works fine.

I want to make `format()` function *formatting* all the dictionary and its branches. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: With a recursive function that walks dicts and lists.

Comment: @AKX
Can you explain more? I am new in python. Thank you  for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function that traverses dicts and lists (and possibly tuples and other things, but those aren't present in your example).

```
from pprint import pprint

info = {
    "name": "Naser",
    "key1": "Good morning {name}",
    "key2": "Good evening {name}",
    "key3": "Good night {name}",
    "list1": ["word1", "word2", {"user": "{name}"}],
}


def recursive_format(obj, info):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {
            recursive_format(key, info): recursive_format(value, info)
            for key, value in obj.items()
        }
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [recursive_format(value, info) for value in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.format_map(info)
    return obj


formatted_info = recursive_format(info, info)
pprint(formatted_info)
```

outputs

```
{'key1': 'Good morning Naser',
 'key2': 'Good evening Naser',
 'key3': 'Good night Naser',
 'list1': ['word1', 'word2', {'user': 'Naser'}],
 'name': 'Naser'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can you explain what `recursive_format(key, info): recursive_format(value, info)` means?
I am new in python, and I didn't understand. is it way to redefine the function or what?
Sorry for disturbing you

Comment: It's part of a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: sorry for disturb you
the link doesn't include any thing about repeating same function:
`recursive_format(key, info): recursive_format(value, info)`

Comment: @NaserOwaimer Sure it does – see the text starting "In addition, dict comprehensions" and compare it to this function.

Comment: Yes yes, I can understand it! , thank you very much
Also i found this in internet: [Recursion in Python: An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-recursion/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'v get problem when use this function in much data.
`ValueError: expected '}' before end of string`
I've searched very much to get any information may help me, but I didn't find any thing.
The 'Traceback' pointed out this line: `return obj.format_map(info)` and all returns in the function. Also pointed the calling of function.
Thank you

Comment: @NaserOwaimer That indicates that _some_ data you're formatting is malformed. You can try adding e.g. `print(obj, info)` to just before the `format_map` call to see what the culprit is, and then fix it in your data.

Comment: Thank you again for replying
I'm using `request` to make GET and POST _requests_, and then assign it to variable to save it as dict using `json` library. 
I've many info inside list, and I'm using for loop to make request based on list information (list information is numbers that i need to send with request headers). I need `format` to format information inside that foo loop. and always first three request done will, but when start on forth or fifth request the program stops and this message. Even after change request numbers order same problem happen.Thank you for help.

Comment: Hello, I think I found the problem.
The problem was in brackets '{'  without closing, in my request data. and its in this HTML element:
`<mfenced close="" open="{">....`
this element is made for typing math equations.
and this property "`open='{'`" is not important and i can delete it.
i think i'll add in my python code some lines to find and remove it.
thank you very much for help.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the dict to JSON, then substitute words, then convert it back. It's probably not too performant, but is a rather simple solution that works regardless of the contents or object types stored:

```py
import json

# substitution code
str = json.dumps(info) # converts dict to JSON string
str.replace("{name}","some name") # do all your replacements here
str.replace("{pet}","dog") # additional changes are separate rows
info = json.loads(str) # update dict
```

With this variant, you specifically can't use string.format(), as `{` and `}` have to be escaped (JSON format uses these 2 symbols extensively).